# JSON decode reads only integer in PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I'm trying to read the query string (which is alphanumeric) on load the page using angular js and send it to php side. But somehow it reads only integer. Here is my code:

**URL:**

> http://www.mydomain.com?token=5c1a45c

**Angular JS Code:**

```
App.controller('reset',['Auth','$scope','$location','$http',function (Auth,$scope,$location,$http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.token = $location.search().token;
        $http.post('controller/reset.php',$scope.token).success(function(data){
                alert('success = '+data);
        }).error(function(e){
                alert('error in request');
        })
    }
    $scope.init();
}])
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));->data;
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
?>
```

I'm alerting the data coming from PHP and it comes **success=5** while it should show me **success=5c1a45c**

I can't find the reason why it behaves like this while I'm using the same method to validate the login and works fine.

Can anyone please help me to fill the gap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show me the input content

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); print_r($data); show your data

Comment: @RakeshSharma it returns **success=5** that means $data=5 only.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad I don't use any element of input I read the query string from URL and URL is **http://www.mydomain.com?token=5c1a45c**

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to say, can you give me the content of the url?